# Custom wxDataObject format for XML for copy-paste support

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to implement a custom data object for XML strings, so that if it exists in the clipboard I can parse that accordingly. The code for the XMLDataObject is as follows:

```
class XMLDataFormat : public wxDataFormat
{
public:
    XMLDataFormat() : wxDataFormat(wxT("XMLDataFormat")) {}
};

class XMLDataObject : public wxDataObjectSimple
{

public:
    XMLDataObject(const wxString& xmlstring = wxEmptyString) : wxDataObjectSimple(), m_XMLString(xmlstring)
    {
        SetFormat(XMLDataFormat());
    }


    size_t GetLength() const { return m_XMLString.Len() + 1; }
    wxString GetXML() const { return m_XMLString; }
    void SetXML(const wxString& xml) { m_XMLString = xml; }

    // Must provide overloads to avoid hiding them (and warnings about it)
    size_t GetDataSize() const
    {
        return sizeof(void*); //or return GetLength() 
    }

    bool GetDataHere(void *buf) const
    {
        char* c = _strdup(m_XMLString.c_str());

        buf = (void*)c;
        return true;
    }

    bool SetData(size_t len, const void* buf)
    {
        char* c = (char*)buf;
        std::string stdString(c, len);
        m_XMLString << stdString;
        return true;
    }


private:
    wxString m_XMLString;
};
```

I send the data to clipboard (when user clicks copy) in the following fashion:

```
wxDataObjectComposite* dataobj = new wxDataObjectComposite();
dataobj->Add(new XMLDataObject("XML"));
if (wxTheClipboard->Open()) wxTheClipboard->SetData(dataobj);
wxTheClipboard->Close();
```

To get the data from the clipboard:

```
if (wxTheClipboard->Open()) {
    XMLDataObject xmlObj;
    wxTheClipboard->GetData(xmlObj);
    if (xmlObj.GetLength() != 0) wxMessageBox(xmlObj.GetXML());
}
wxTheClipboard->Close();
```

When user clicks paste, I get weird characters instead of the text "XML". I realized that in the functions `bool GetDataHere(void *buf) const` and `bool SetData(size_t len, const void* buf)` the address of `buf` is different. I am not sure but *maybe* that is how it should be since Clipboard owns the data or behind the scenes wxWidgets is doing something.

By the way, I am using VS 2015 on Windows 10 and using wxWidgets 3.1.0.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code so far has worked correctly:

```
class XMLDataFormat : public wxDataFormat
{
public:
    XMLDataFormat() : wxDataFormat(wxT("XMLDataFormat")) {}
};

class XMLDataObject : public wxDataObjectSimple
{

public:
    XMLDataObject(const wxString& xmlstring = wxEmptyString) : wxDataObjectSimple(), m_XMLString(xmlstring)
    {
        SetFormat(XMLDataFormat());
    }


    size_t GetLength() const { return m_XMLString.Len() + 1; }
    wxString GetXML() const { return m_XMLString; }
    void SetXML(const wxString& xml) { m_XMLString = xml; }

    size_t GetDataSize() const
    {
        return GetLength();
    }

    bool GetDataHere(void *buf) const
    {
        //char* c = _strdup(m_XMLString.c_str()); not needed as per suggestion

        memcpy(buf, m_XMLString.c_str(), m_XMLString.Len()+1);
        return true;
    }

    bool SetData(size_t len, const void* buf)
    {
        //char* c = new char[len + 1]; not needed as per suggestion
        //memcpy(c, buf, len); not needed as per suggestion
        m_XMLString = wxString::FromUTF8((const char*)buf); //changed as per suggestion

        //delete c;

        return true;
    }

    virtual size_t GetDataSize(const wxDataFormat&) const 
    {
        return GetDataSize();
    }
    virtual bool GetDataHere(const wxDataFormat&, void *buf) const 
    {
        return GetDataHere(buf);
    }
    virtual bool SetData(const wxDataFormat&, size_t len, const void *buf) 
    {
        return SetData(len, buf);
    }


private:
    wxString m_XMLString;
};
```

Any suggestions as to improve it is again appreciated.

Comment: You're leaking memory in `GetDataHere()`, to fix it, just don't call `_strdup()` at all and `memcpy()` string data directly into the provided buffer. Similarly, although less seriously as you do free memory here, there is no need for intermediate `memcpy()` in `SetData()`, you can call `FromUTF8()` directly on the provided data (and pass it the length, too).

Comment: @VZ: I fixed `GetDataHere()` by `memcpy(buf, m_XMLString.c_str(), m_XMLString.Len()+1)` and `SetData()` by `m_XMLString = wxString::FromUTF8((const char*)buf);` and it again works correctly and I believe more efficiently now, thanks for this! By the way, I understand that the data in `void* buf` is preserved once I `memcpy` it in `GetDataHere()`. I guess this is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, data in `buf` passed to `GetDataHere()` is what actually ends up in the system clipboard, so it is not destroyed until it's not needed any more.